# Jenkins declarative pipeline - dynamicaly set stages (store in variable) and run one by one

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to create pipeline in which it will be possible to select option to run stages in parallel or sequentialy.

Stages are defined like that:

```
tests = [:] 
for (String fileName: getTestsStages()) {
  tests["${fileName}"] = {
    stage ("Run Stage ${fileName}") {
      println("Hello ${fileName}")
    }
  }
```

Now I want to make it possible to run this tests in parallel or sequentialy:

```
if (runParallel) {
  parallel tests
} else {
  tests
}
```

While parallel execution works as expected, sequential execution is not working (stages are not recognized).
I tried also with forEach:

```
tests.each{ test -> test }
```

But it also didn't recognized and run stages.

Comment: `tests.each{ test -> test }` does not call the closure, because test is a map entry not a closure. Try `tests.each { name, stage -> stage() }`

Comment: @smelm Thank you, now it's works as expected.